# Cannot use the current() function in a non-XSLT context

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

Our situation is that we need to support XPath 1.0 and function `current()` (and a few other functions) in our models but we don't have data as XML documents. 
We wrote a NodeInfo implementation to handle the non-XML data source problem.

but, when I ran an expression of the following kind

```
/a/b/c[name = current()/../x]/yy/uu/name
```

by setting an object representing the root as the document object and another object with sibling element x as the context node, I got the error

> Cannot use the current() function in a non-XSLT context

When I debugged I saw that the context in use is the standalonecontext. How can I get the support for the `current()` function ? I tried by changing the expression to

```
/a/b/c[name = ./../x]/yy/uu/name
```

but, the `.` is interpreted as the `c`.

Comment: Which version of Saxon exactly do you use that with? Why does it have to be XPath 1.0, if you use Saxon 9 then you have XPath 2.0 or in 9.7 even XPath 3.0 (where you could use e.g. `let $context := . return /a/b/c[name = $context/../x]/yy/uu/name`).

Comment: there is a spec given to me that I need to support. The spec limits to xpath 1.0 and some borrowed functions like current().

Comment: There is a spec given to me that I need to support. The spec limits to xpath 1.0 and some borrowed functions like current(). My implementation may use any thing, so saxon 9.7 is certainly an option, provided it is possible to do a custom NodeInfo implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon adopts a very strict attitude to conformance, and the XPath specification does not allow implementors to add their own functions except in a different namespace. The current() function is defined in XSLT, and the semantics of the function are defined in terms that only make sense in XSLT, although one could certainly define an analogous function for use in free-standing XPath expressions. In current versions of XPath it really isn't needed any more, because you can bind variables using "let" (as Martin Honnen shows).

If you're prepared to get deep into internal interfaces, then Saxon does allow you to extend the set of functions available. There are XForms implementations, for example, that use the Saxon engine underneath, with additional functions that are defined in the XForms specification. The details would depend on which Saxon version you are using: the fact that the static context is a StandaloneContext suggests that it's a rather old version. If you were using 9.7, it would probably be an IndependentContext. The IndependentContext has methods `getFunctionLibrary()` and `setFunctionLibrary()` that can be used to modify the set of functions known to the XPath parser. But to make this work you'll have to become fairly familiar with the internals of Saxon. But if you are really obliged to implement a specification that extends XPath 1.0 in a non-conformant way, then you don't have many options.

Comment: I have no option but to support that thing. Thank you. I will look into 9.7. I need to use the open source library (and a license that does not need us to open our code) . We will be glad to contribute the customization code but cannot reveal any of the application code. Does Saxon 9.7 allows for that ?

Comment: The Mozilla license requires you to publish modifications to existing modules but you can add new modules of your own without publishing them. You can meet the letter of that requirement by modifying existing modules to call your own new modules at appropriate points - your modified code doesn't even need to clean compile on its own. Crazy, but this was all written by lawyers who are clueless about technology.